# Regular Expression to match at least 4 character

Tags: c#, regex

I want to do password validation in which user first name and last name should not be part of password.

for example *mary maverick* is username and assume that user has entered password like `Test123%mave` or `Test123%rick` or `Test123%ryma` in this case validation should be failed in C# code.

Can any one please help me or guide me how can I write regular expression ?

Comment: Why do you want to use a regex for this? It's not really a typical application for it and a dedicated algorithm will probably be much faster. It this an assignment?

Comment: Hi  Nebula, I am just trying to avoid c# code for this validation and trying to use reg expression as far as I know reg exp is much faster to do validation. correct me here If I am wrong here.

Comment: No usually RegEx's are slower since they 'brute-force' a query on the data. See http://theburningmonk.com/2012/05/performance-test-string-contains-vs-string-indexof-vs-regex-ismatch/ for example. Algorithms tend to be faster since they are tailored to the problem. Also, in your case, I think the RegEx would get pretty complex (==slow) since you are also windowing over the user name. For instance: what are the minimum amount of characters that **are** allowed to match? You can't exclude them all right =)

Comment: thanks Nebula for your information, this really helps to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code works based on your scenario:

```
            string username = "mary maverick";
            string password = "Test123%mave";
            username = username.Replace(" ", "");
            for (int i = 0; i < password.Length; i++)
            {
                if (i + 4 <= password.Length)
                {
                    string temp = password.Substring(i,  4);
                    if (username.Contains(temp))
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Faild!");
                        return;
                    }
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Accepted!");
```

You can replace `password` with whatever you want to set as the password.

Comment: Hi Saman your c# code is perfect for my requirement, but I want to achieve it only through regular expression.

Comment: @ManojSitapara I don't know why you want to do this only through regex, but if I were you I would make a simple function for that and use it, it wouldn't be a big deal!

Comment: Thanks Saman. finally I have dropped my plan to use regular expression.

Comment: @ManojSitapara OK, please select the answer as the best if you think it worth.

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be easier to achieve what you are after by using a simple algorithm, and not a regular expression since you are not looking for a predefined pattern, but you just need to know if characters within the password are in the same order as those stored within the user name.

To achieve this, you could:

1. Select the shortest string.
2. For each character in `c` in `1`, seek the same character in the longer string.
3. If found, check to see if the character which follows `c` also follows the other character in the longer string. If yes, move to the character which follows (keep going till you match 4 successive characters), if not, then change `c` to the character which follows (within the shorter string).
4. Repeat until you run out of characters (you go through the shortest string).